# Removing NULL from field

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file from which I have to fetch a field (first field). It comes as:

```
ITD330 OPS 301 D03
```

I need to fetch only `ITD330`, but a NULL comes after `ITD330` so it prints `ITD330OPS` completely. How to resolve it?

Comment: You should consider adding a code example that results in the malformed output. Also indicating what tools are used  will allow for more tailored answers.

Comment: Tools?didn't get you..

Comment: What command changes the input into the malformed output?

Comment: Its not an output.My file which is input for my script contains NULL.eg:  ITD330 OPS 301 D03 is actually as " ITD330^@OPS 301 D03" where ^@ is a NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by “NULL“ you mean the [null character (NUL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) you can use one of the following commands to print the first field of every line:

```bsh
awk -F\0 '{print$1}' # replace “1” by “2” for the second field etc.
sed 's/\x0.*//'
```

If you want to replace every NUL character by space or newline, use `tr`:

```bsh
tr '\0' ' '  # replace by space
tr '\0' '\n' # replace by newline
```

Comment: thnaks..It helped